# Check if name is different of an ID in production and pre-production DB's

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 DB's pre-production and production. I  have a table in which is present in both DB's. I am running a query which checks if the Id's of the column is present in pre-production and production DB, which gives me the Id's which are not there in production DB. Following is the query

```
SELECT 'test',ID,NULL,NULL,'I',NULL,NULL,NULL FROM [pre-prod].dbo.Tb1 WHERE ID 
IN (SELECT ID FROM [pre-prod].dbo.TB1 EXCEPT (SELECT ID FROM [prod].dbo.TB1)).
```

Now I am trying to get the details of the Id's which are present in both the tables in `pre-prod` and `prod` DB but with different name.

Please help as to what should be the query.

Comment: Have you tried using EXISTS? Try something like "select from pre prod pp where exists (select 1 from prod p where p.id = pp.id and p.name <> pp.name)"

Comment: You can also use except with only ID and name columns in select clause

Comment: I am not getting what you saying. I am new to SQl , can you please elaborate

Comment: I will elaborate the except part use: "select id,name from prod except select id,name from pre-prod". This will give you list of same ids having different names

Answer (score 0):

Try this query..

Matching records id both PreProductionDB and ProductionDB but different name..

```
  SELECT a.id,a.name,b.name FROM [PreProductionDB].[dbo].tbl1 a join  [ProductionDB].[dbo].tbl1  b
   on a.id=b.id where  a.Name<>b.Name
```